# Solve a Diophantine equation for a specific value of $x$

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations, problem-solving, elliptic-curves, integers

I have the following problem:

> Prove that there exists some $x\in\mathbb{N}$ with $x>7$, such that the following equation has no solution $(k,n)$, where $k,n\in\mathbb{N}$ with $k>3$ and $n>4$:
>
> $$k(k+1)(kx+3-x)=3n(nx+2-x)$$

---

I have no idea how to start on this problem, is there a smart way to choose the value of $x$? My professor did mention choosing a smart value of $x$, but I do not know what a smart way is to choose that smart value.

Comment: Counterexamples `(x,k,n)=(8,5,7),(12,6,9),(86,15,34),(28,17,41),(9,25,73),(274,26,77),(320,28,86),...`. May be mistake in problem?

Comment: @DmitryEzhov No it is not a mistake in the problem, there are values of $x$ where there are no solutions and the question is to find such a value of $x$ and prove that for that specific value there is no solution. The question does not say that for all $x>7$ it has to be true.

Answer (score 0):

The equation is linear in $x$. Expanding and collecting terms yields
$$\big(3n(n-1)-k(k+1)(k-1)\big)x=3k(k+1)-6.$$
Note that all terms are divisible by $6$, and we can express the fractions as binomial coefficients:
$$\left(\binom{n}{2}-\binom{k+1}{3}\right)x=\binom{k+1}{2}-1.$$
From here you can use Pascal's rule to find a 'smart' value of $x$.